# Why does `read` not pick up all my vars?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, read

Why the following does not print 3 2 1 6 5 4?

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | while read a b c; do echo result: $c b a; done
```

Wouldn't the first three numbers be read in order, printed in reverse, and then the last three numbers read and reversed?

Answer (score 10):

You provided a line with 6 "words", yet you're reading them into three variables: a, b, and c. The first variable a is assigned 1, the second variable b is assigned 2, and c gets to hold the rest of the line: "3 4 5 6".

The output is `3 4 5 6 b a` because you didn't write `$c $b $a`, but only `$c b a`.

If you had written `$c $b $a`, the result would have been `3 4 5 6 2 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The key point that is confusing you, which the other answer skims over,
can be seen in [the bash man page](http://man.cx/bash):

> **`read`** *…(options)…* **`[name ...]`**
>
>   **One line is read from the standard input,**
>   …,
>     and the first word is assigned to the first
>   *name*
>   ,
>     the second word to the second
>   *name*
>   , and so on,
>     with leftover words and their intervening separators
>     assigned to the last
>   *name*
>   .  …
>   <sub>[Emphasis added.]</sub>

or in the output of `help read`:

> read *…(options)…* [*name* ...]
>
>   **Read a line from the standard input**
>   and split it into fields.
>
> **Reads *a single line* from the standard input,** …. 
>   The line is split into fields as with word splitting,
>   and the first word is assigned to the first NAME,
>   the second word to the second NAME, and so on,
>   with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME.  …

The point: `read` never reads more than one line.

Comment: Actually, the point that is confusing the OP is that `read` reads a *whole* line. Here there's a single line of input, but the OP expected the loop body to run twice.

Comment: Ah, true; `read` never reads *less* than one line (although that's not exactly true, either).  I always get [those concepts](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/96107) mixed up.    :-)    ⁠